# Haskell need help understanding stream

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, stream, read-eval-print-loop, ghci

I have this code where these functions have been made:

1. creates an infinite list out of the given stream;
2. creates a stream for the given iteration function and the starting stream element (seed);
3. merges two streams into one so that their elements are interleaved.

The code is as follows:

```
data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)

streamToList :: Stream a -> [a]
streamToList (Cons x xs) = x : streamToList xs

streamIterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> Stream a
streamIterate f x = Cons x (streamIterate f (f x))

streamIterLeave :: Stream a -> Stream a -> Stream a
streamIterLeave (Cons x xs) ys = Cons x (streamIterLeave ys xs)
```

Now what I am having problems with is I have no idea how to check this code on ghci. To be more specific, how do I input a stream into the command line?

For example I tried `streamToList [1,2,3]` ; `streamToList (1,2,3)`; `streamToList 1,2,3` and none of them seem to be working.

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: You cannot construct a finite stream, because you don't have the empty case. Hence you cannot construct one manually like `Cons 'a' (Cons 'b' (...))`. However, you can rely on infinite recursion: `foo i = Cons i (foo $ i + 1)`.

Comment: You could try `s1 = streamIterate (+2) 0`, `s2 = streamIterate (+2) 1`, and then `take 20 $ streamToList s1`, the same with `s2`, or even `take20 $ streamToList $ streamInterleave s1 s2`.

Comment: Note that none of your attempts construct `Stream` values; you have lists, tuples, and syntax errors, respectively. The only way to construct a `Stream` value is with `Cons`, so (co)recuson is necessary.

Comment: @IvenMarquardt one tends to forget about `undefined`. :) `take 2 $ streamToList $ Cons 1 $ Cons 2 undefined` works.

Answer (score 1):

Several ways. The simplest is just using `undefined`:

```
> take 2 $ streamToList $ Cons 1 $ Cons 2 undefined
[1,2]
```

You can defined named streams at the prompt,

```
> let { one = Cons 1 two ; two = Cons 2 one }
```

or with multi-line input,

```
> :{
| one = Cons 1 two
| two = Cons 2 one
| :}

> take 5 $ streamToList one
[1,2,1,2,1]
```

and you can use your `streamIterate` as shown in the comments or use `foldr` to create your streams from lists,

```
> take 5 $ streamToList $ streamIterate (+1) 0
[0,1,2,3,4]
> listToStream xs = foldr Cons undefined xs
> intS = listToStream [1..]
> take 5 $ streamToList intS 
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Having defined `listToStream` you can further easily define

```
> mapStream f s = listToStream . map f . streamToList $ s
> intsStream = x where { x = Cons 1 $ mapStream (1+) x }
> take 5 $ streamToList intsStream
[1,2,3,4,5]
> zipStr s1 s2 = listToStream $ zip (streamToList s1) (streamToList s2)
> zipStrWith f s1 s2 = mapStream (uncurry f) (zipStr s1 s2)
> addStreams s1 s2 = zipStrWith (+) s1 s2
> fibS = let {a = Cons 0 b; b = Cons 1 c; c = addStreams a b} in a
> take 15 $ streamToList fibS
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377]
```

etc. etc. etc.

---

as [dfeuer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477667/dfeuer) mentions in the comments, `listToStream` above is a bit bogus -- it allows for invalid (i.e. finite) lists as its argument. It's OK for playing with it at the REPL, but not in general.

It could be better to "pull the bogosity out to the call site", by defining

```
> :{ 
| (+++) :: [a] -> Stream a -> Stream a
| xs +++ ys  =  foldr Cons ys xs
| :}
```

allowing us to define streams like

```
> good = [1..] +++ undefined
> bad = [1..10] +++ undefined
```

where the problem, if present, is more immediately apparent.

Comment: `listToStream` is a bit bogus. Perhaps it would be better to pull the bogosity out to the call site, using the totally reasonable `(+++) :: [a] -> Stream a -> Stream a; xs +++ ys = foldr Cons ys xs`.

Comment: @dfeuer interesting idea, thanks.